# Raspbian filesystem user permissions

Tags: files, permissions, raspbian

There's something strange on the Raspbian linux about file permissions:
Logging in with the default pi user end executing

```
sudo touch new_file
```

and then

```
ls -l new_file
```

yields

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 May 28 09:33 new_file
```

but then,without sudo I can delete the file with

```
rm new_file
```

Even if it prompts the following

```
rm: remove write-protected regular empty file 'new_file'? y
```

Pressing y the file is deleted.How is that possible?

Comment: by default user `pi` is given many root privilege which enables user to do sudo tasks without explicitly adding `sudo`

Comment: The term here would then be `capabilities(7)` or group memberships.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you can delete the file `new_file` despite not being its owner, is because you have write permissions to the directory that holds `new_file` (this directory is probably pi's home directory.)

You can check this with `stat .`

It's also worth mentioning that if the directory has the sticky bit enabled (for example, `/tmp`), then having write permissions in the directory isn't sufficient to allow you to delete contained files.

Comment: Note you are not deleting the file, you are removing (rm), the entry from the directory (you have write permission on this directory). If there are no references left to the file (no directory entries, and no processes have the file open), then the OS will garbage collect it: delete it (Unix uses a reference counting garbage collector).

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the file because the user `pi` has all permissions in his home directory `/home/pi`.
If you create another file under another directory that doesn't belong to the user `pi`, for example

```
cd /
touch file
```

you can't rm it.

Comment: so why can't I touch anything in directories that are upper than the home directory in the filesystem tree without sudo?

Comment: Ok,that's because the folder permissions

Comment: My response was incorrect, I edited it.

Comment: @AntonioDelSannio do you mean below (not above). I know every one seems to draw trees upside down. With the root in the air, but they are wrong. The root is at (in) the ground.